when will the expression be non-negative?
We have $x\in X=\{x_1,...,x_M \}$, $y\in Y=\{y_1,...,y_N\}$, $\theta\in \Theta=\{\theta_L, \theta_H\}$ where $\theta_L < \theta_H$.
Let $f_1(x, y)=\theta_L[\Pr(\theta_L)\Pr(x, y\mid \theta_L)+\Pr(\theta_H)\Pr(x, y\mid \theta_H)]$, $f_2(x, y)=\theta_H\Pr(\theta_H)\Pr(x, y\mid \theta_H)$.
We know $\Pr(x, y\mid \theta)\in [0, 1]$, $\sum_x \sum_y\Pr(x, y\mid \theta_L)=1$, $\sum_x \sum_y\Pr(x, y\mid \theta_H)=1$. Also, if $\Pr(x, y\mid \theta_L)>0$, then $\Pr(x, y\mid \theta_H)=0$ and if $\Pr(x, y\mid \theta_H)>0$, then $\Pr(x, y\mid \theta_L)=0$.
how to prove the following expression is non-negative?
$\sum_x \sum_y \max \{f_1(x, y), f_2(x, y)\}-\sum_x \max \{\sum_y f_1(x, y), \sum_y f_2(x, y)\}-\sum_y \max \{\sum_x f_1(x, y), \sum_x f_2(x, y)\}+\max \{\sum_x \sum_y f_1(x, y), \sum_x\sum_y f_2(x, y)\}$

Without knowing what the functions $f_1,f_2$ are, it is unlikely that much can be said.  You might want to explore some simplified problem, perhaps with $i,j$ limited to one or two values.  At present the Question, in addition to omitting the key information just discussed, lacks enough context to meet the Math.SE community standards.

Thank you for your comments and I have updated the question.

Thanks for updating the body of your Question.  Such context makes the problem more interesting and gives Readers an idea what kind of responses will be helpful.
